# Xterm Ctrl+Arrow shortcut keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

I'm using xterm version 293. While navigating in a command, I normally use the short-cut keys as `Ctrl+LeftArrow` or `Ctrl+RightArrow` to move back and forth.

But while doing so, rather expected behaviour, `Ctrl+LeftArrow` prints **5D** and `Ctrl+RightArrow` prints **5C**

How to make the `xterm` work as per expectation ?

**EDIT:**

e.g. In xterm, if I type:

```
shw$ This is a test
```

If the cursor is after **is** and I press `Ctrl+LeftArrow`, then I'm expecting that cursor should move On **i** of is (and again pressing `Ctrl+LeftArrow`, cursor must go at **T** of This). But instead, I get the result as

```
shw$ This is5D a test
```

Same for `Ctrl+RightArrow`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To support Ctrl-arrows in xterm, set the `modifyKeyboard` resource to at least 2. For instance:

```
xterm -xrm "*modifyKeyboard: 2"
```

If this doesn't have the expected behavior, perhaps your application (its key bindings) is not correctly configured. Or you can also try to modify the `modifyCursorKeys` resource, e.g.

```
xterm -xrm "*modifyKeyboard: 2" -xrm "*modifyCursorKeys: 0"
```

You need to configure your applications to recognize the escape sequences. For instance, with `*modifyCursorKeys: 2` (which is the default) and zsh:

```
bindkey '\e[1;5C' forward-word
bindkey '\e[1;5D' backward-word
```

and for applications based on libreadline, such as bash:

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
```

in your `~/.inputrc` file.

Comment: First command have no effect. Second command also have no effect except, `5D` and `5C` is not getting printed

Comment: @SHW You need to give more information. For instance, where do you get the expected behavior?

Comment: See the edited question

Comment: @SHW Well, xterm works as expected. The problem should come from your applications, which need to be configured. See my edited answer for zsh and readline based applications. If this still doesn't work for you, you should give more details.

Comment: Thanks. `libreadline` solution is working

Comment: Modifying `~/.inputrc` resolved the issue. Thanks.